# calling drop down function in a php table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone  i am quite new to php and i am trying to impement a drop down menu in a php table , the code of the table is the one below

```
 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($availablesitsdata)) {
   echo "<form action=selectsits.php enctype=multipart/form-data method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .  $record['Zone'] .  "</td>";
        $nameofzone = $record['Zone'];
        echo "<td>" . "<select type=text name=sit value=" .tickets_Num(). "> </select></td>";        
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update > </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

i am trying to call the function ticket_Num() , which contains all the attributes of the drop down menu , i manage to call the function but the attributes of the drop down menu are outside the table the code of my function is

```
Function tickets_Num(){
?>
<option value="Select">Select Number of Tickets</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>            
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<?php
}
```

can anyone  please help me ?

Comment: I think this is not how it should be done. Give me sec to prepare you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first `<select>` haven't value attribute, but `<option>` has, so try this

```
 echo "<td>" . "<select type=text name=sit>" .tickets_Num(). " </select></td>"; 

Function tickets_Num(){
    return 
    '<option value="Select">Select Number of Tickets</option>
    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Sergey , it worked just like the way i wanted

Comment: @user3397260 It's polite that you mark the answer that helped you, by clicking the green "check" next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($availablesitsdata)) {
   echo "<form action=selectsits.php enctype=multipart/form-data method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .  $record['Zone'] .  "</td>";
        $nameofzone = $record['Zone'];
        echo "<td>" . "<select type='text' name='sit'>".tickets_Num()." </select></td>";        
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='update' value='update' > </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

And if you want to have it in function then maybe like this you can try

```
Function tickets_Num(){
return '<option value="Select">Select Number of Tickets</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>            
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>'
}
```

But be aware that this usage of function is a nonsence and im shouwing it to you because maybe you have some code that will generate your thml code and then return variable. Otherwise dont write functions like this.

Comment: `name=sit value=" .tickets_Num(). "> </select>` probably should be `name='sit' >" .tickets_Num(). "</select>` as `select` doesn't have a value, and the options should be within the `<select></select>`.

Comment: true didnt pay attention to much to this sorry

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there are many missing "quotes" in your loop... @Standej has pointed out the issue with your function so this is in addition to his answer.

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($availablesitsdata)) {
    $nameofzone = $record['Zone'];
?>

   <form action="selectsits.php" enctype="multipart/form-data method=post">
       <tr>
       <td><?= $record['Zone']?></td>
       <td><select type="text" name="sit" value="<?php= tickets_Num() ?>"></select></td>      
       <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="update" ></td>
       </tr>
    </form>

<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include your all form elements in the while loop.
`echo "<form action=selectsits.php enctype=multipart/form-data method=post>";`
Every time you are including this but 1 time is enough. Just Put your `<option>` labels in the loop.

```
<form action="ddd.php">

    <select name="kkk">

                <option value='#'>Select</option>
                <?php
                while ($sonuc = mysqli_fetch_array($sorgula)) {

                    echo"<option value='$sonuc[0]'>$sonuc[0]</option>";

                }
                ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: He may want individual forms though.

Comment: Then ok. Just put <option> elements in the loop.